# usage of the READTEXT method in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2000

According to this link on microsoft MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933206(v=sql.80)

This is the Syntax for the insert statement.

```
Syntax

INSERT [ INTO] 
    { table_name WITH ( < table_hint_limited > [ ...n ] ) 
        | view_name 
        | rowset_function_limited 
    } 

    {    [ ( column_list ) ] 
        { VALUES 
            ( { DEFAULT | NULL | expression } [ ,...n] ) 
            | derived_table 
            | execute_statement 
        } 
    } 
    | DEFAULT VALUES

< table_hint_limited > ::= 
    { FASTFIRSTROW 
        | HOLDLOCK 
        | PAGLOCK 
        | READCOMMITTED 
        | REPEATABLEREAD 
        | ROWLOCK 
        | SERIALIZABLE 
        | TABLOCK 
        | TABLOCKX 
        | UPDLOCK 
    }
```

Further in the documentation, it defines "*execute_statement*" in the VALUES clause as such:

> execute_statement
>
> Is any valid EXECUTE statement that returns data with SELECT or
>   **READTEXT** statements.

I have tried the following format in a stored procedure:

```
  INSERT INTO #MANAGERS (MANAGERCHARS) 
      READTEXT #MANAGERS.MANAGERIDS @ptrval @CharIndex 1
```

and get the following error:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure usp_TestQualityMonitor, Line 117
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'READTEXT'.
```

According to the documentation that I've went over in this question, READTEXT should be a valid method as an execute_statement, so what am I doing wrong?  Why am I getting this message? and just how can I format this statement correctly without an error?

NOTE:  fixed the SQL by removing the "VALUES".  Still getting same error.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the syntax diagram carefully, you can use either

(a) VALUES (etc.)

OR

(b) a derived table

OR

(c) execute_statement

You can't say:

```
INSERT dbo.table VALUES(EXEC dbo.procedure);
```

However you *can* say:

```
INSERT dbo.table EXEC dbo.procedure;
```

(Depending of course on what dbo.procedure does.)

So perhaps you could try:

```
INSERT INTO #MANAGERS (MANAGERCHARS) --VALUES 
  READTEXT #MANAGERS.MANAGERIDS @ptrval @CharIndex 1;
```

However I am not 100% that `READTEXT` is a valid execute statement in this context.

---

After the update of what you're actually trying to do, how about a split function?

First, create a numbers table:

```
SELECT n = IDENTITY(INT, 1, 1) INTO dbo.Numbers
FROM syscolumns CROSS JOIN syscolumns AS c2;

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX n ON dbo.Numbers(n);
```

On my SQL Server 2000 system this creates 66,000+ rows, so it will support a string over 64K. You may need to add an additional cross join if your strings will be longer than this.

Now, create a split function that will handle NTEXT (most you'll find these days won't bother, since NTEXT is deprecated and most people have been able to discard SQL Server 2000 entirely). I don't remember where I originally sourced this one but I have been using it for several years:

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.Split_NTEXT
(
  @list      NTEXT,
  @delimiter CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @table TABLE
(
  string NVARCHAR(4000)
)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @chunks TABLE (chunk NVARCHAR(4000) NOT NULL);

  DECLARE @chunk NVARCHAR(4000), @p INT, @ml INT, @e INT;

  SELECT @p = 1, @ml = 3998;

  WHILE (DATALENGTH(@list)/2) - (@p-1) >= @ml
  BEGIN
   SET @chunk = SUBSTRING(@list, @p, @ml);
   SET @e = @ml - CHARINDEX(@delimiter, REVERSE(@chunk));
   INSERT @chunks(chunk) SELECT @delimiter + SUBSTRING(@chunk, 1, @e) + @delimiter;
   SET @p = @p - 1 + @e + 2;
  END
  INSERT @chunks(chunk) SELECT @delimiter + SUBSTRING(@list, @p, @ml) + @delimiter;

  INSERT @table(string) SELECT s = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(s.chunk, n.n + 1,
        CHARINDEX(@delimiter, s.chunk, n.n + 1) - n.n - 1)))
      FROM dbo.Numbers AS n INNER JOIN @chunks AS s 
        ON n.n <= LEN(s.chunk) - 1
        AND SUBSTRING(s.chunk, n.n, 1) = @delimiter;
  RETURN;
END
GO
```

Usage:

```
SELECT string
  FROM dbo.Split_NTEXT(N'foo,bar,blat,mort,splunge', ',');
```

Results:

```
string
--------
foo
bar
blat
mort
splunge
```

This won't be extraordinarily fast compared to more modern methods such as [CLR](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) or [TVP](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-now-with-less-t-sql), but should be relatively much less hassle than dealing with READTEXT or other arcane methods you may think you are stuck with in 2000.

Comment: I originally tried this both ways, neither made a difference.  In what context would READTEXT be a valid execute statement?  I'm trying to do something yet again in my code that most everyone I've talked to says is impossible in SQL Server 2000 which I feel should not only be possible, but should be easy... parsing a large CSV string passed to a stored proc as an NTEXT variable type. READTEXT is my latest attempt at solving this issue.

Comment: READTEXT would be a valid execute statement on its own. I don't know if it can be used as the source of an insert, and it's been a long time since I played in 2000. As for your actual problem, have you considered a split function? If you search this site you should find plenty of 2000-compatible examples.